# Azure Pipelines: Build a specific stage in a multistage Dockerfile without building non-dependent stages

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a multistage Dockerfile containing the following stages:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-bullseye as python-base
# ...

FROM python-base as builder-base
# ...

FROM python-base as runtime-deps
# ...

FROM runtime-deps as dev-deps
# ...

FROM dev-deps as development
# ...

FROM runtime-deps as cloud
# ...
```

You can see how these stages depend on each other more visually here: [image: stage dependencies]

The `cloud` stage doesn't depend on `dev-deps` or `development`, yet those stages still get built when I use the [Docker task](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/tasks/build/docker.md) with the arg `--target cloud`:

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build Docker image
  inputs:
  command: build
  repository: $(IMAGE_NAME)
  tags: $(TAG_NAME)
  arguments: '--target cloud'
```

Those unneeded stages also still get built when I run the `docker` command directly in a Bash task:

```yaml
bash: docker build --target cloud --tag $REGISTRY_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME:$TAG_NAME .
```

How can I configure a Docker build in a pipeline so only the specified target stage is built?

Answer (score 1):

As skipping stages only works with Buildkit, and Buildkit doesn't seem to be available in the Docker task or in the `docker` command on Azure Pipelines, you'll have to enable it by using `buildx`, [which uses Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/):

```yaml
- bash: docker buildx build --target cloud --tag $REGISTRY_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME:$TAG_NAME .
```

You could also use the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` environment variable, [as described in the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/):

```yaml
- bash: DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --target cloud --tag $REGISTRY_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME:$TAG_NAME .
```