# "##[error]Error response from daemon: failed to reach build target <stage> in Dockerfile" only during CI pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm getting this error in my PR pipeline and I'm not sure what the cause and solution is.

The Docker task is pretty well templated and the stage does exist in my `Dockerfile`:

```
# docker.yaml
parameters:
- name: service
  default: ''
- name: jobName
  default: ''
- name: jobDisplayName
  default: ''
- name: taskDisplayName
  default: ''
- name: dockerCommand
  default: ''
- name: target
  default: ''
- name: tag
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  displayName: ${{ parameters.jobDisplayName }}
  # Handle whether to run service or not
  variables:
    servicesChanged: $[ stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChanges.servicesChanged'] ]
  condition: or(contains(variables['servicesChanged'], '${{ parameters.service }}'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
  steps: 
  # Set to app repo
  - checkout: app
  # Run the Docker task
  - task: Docker@2
    # Run if there have been changes
    displayName: ${{ parameters.taskDisplayName }}
    inputs:
      command: ${{ parameters.dockerCommand }}
      repository: $(imageRepository)-${{ parameters.service }}
      dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/${{ parameters.service }}/docker/Dockerfile
      buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/${{ parameters.service }}
      containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
      arguments: --target ${{ parameters.target }}
      tags: |
        ${{ parameters.tag }}-$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

```
# Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
# creating a python base with shared environment variables
FROM python:3.8-slim as python-base
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"
ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"


# builder-base is used to build dependencies
FROM python-base as builder-base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        curl \
        build-essential

# Install Poetry - respects $POETRY_VERSION & $POETRY_HOME
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.1.8
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python

# We copy our Python requirements here to cache them
# and install only runtime deps using poetry
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml ./
RUN poetry install --no-dev


# 'development' stage installs all dev deps and can be used to develop code.
# For example using docker-compose to mount local volume under /app
FROM python-base as development

# Copying poetry and venv into image
COPY --from=builder-base $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH

# Copying in our entrypoint
# COPY ./docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x . /opt/pysetup/.venv/bin/activate

# venv already has runtime deps installed we get a quicker install
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
RUN poetry install
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "python", "src/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000"]


# 'unit-tests' stage runs our unit tests with unittest and coverage.  
FROM development AS unit-tests
RUN coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' src/manage.py test src --tag=ut && \
    coverage report
```

The `Dockerfile` is being found correctly and the pipeline looks it starts to build the image, but then throws this error. I can run a `docker build ... --target unit-tests` locally without issue, so it is isolated the Azure Pipelines.

Suggestions for what could be causing this?

---

EDIT:
This is the project structure:

```
app/
  admin/
    docker/
      Dockerfile
      entrypoint.sh
    src/
      ...
  api/
    docker/
      Dockerfile
      entrypoint.sh
    src/
      ...
  portal/
    docker/
      Dockerfile
      entrypoint.sh
    src/
      ...
```

This is a portion of the `devspace.yaml`:

```
admin-ut:
  image: ${APP-NAME}/${ADMIN-UT}
  dockerfile: ${ADMIN}/docker/Dockerfile
  context: ${ADMIN}/
  build:
    buildKit:
      args: []
      options:
        target: unit-tests
```

---

EDIT2:

Maybe the issue is related to not having `BuildKit` per this question:

[Azure Pipelines: Build a specific stage in a multistage Dockerfile without building non-dependent stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179040/azure-pipelines-build-a-specific-stage-in-a-multistage-dockerfile-without-build)

But there is Github issue that is related:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/9196#issuecomment-761624398

So I've modified my `docker.yaml` for Azure Pipelines to:

```
  - task: Docker@2
    # Run if there have been changes
    displayName: ${{ parameters.taskDisplayName }}
    inputs:
      command: ${{ parameters.dockerCommand }}
      repository: $(imageRepository)-${{ parameters.service }}
      dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/${{ parameters.service }}/docker/Dockerfile
      buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/${{ parameters.service }}
      containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
      arguments: --target ${{ parameters.target }}
      tags: |
        ${{ parameters.tag }}-$(Build.BuildNumber)
    env:
      DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
```

Now I get a more verbose error output:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: target stage unit-tests could not be found
##[error]#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
##[error]#1 sha256:acc1b908d881e469d44e7f005ceae0820d5ee08ada351a0aa2a7b8e749c8f6fe
##[error]#1 transferring dockerfile: 974B done
##[error]#1 DONE 0.0s
##[error]#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
##[error]#2 sha256:189c0a02bba84ed5c5f9ea82593d0e664746767c105d65afdf3cd0771eeb378e
##[error]#2 transferring context: 346B done
##[error]#2 DONE 0.0s
##[error]failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: target stage unit-tests could not be found
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do your build contexts match in both Azure Pipelines and locally? I see you're using the command `docker build ... --target unit-tests`, i.e. setting the build context to the parent directory's parent directory, but the Pipeline is only one directory up.

Comment: @NickODell Hi, I've updated my answer to include information related to project structure and local dev setup. But the contexts are the same in both environments. The `Dockerfile` is in a sibling directory to the application code, which is probably an unusual setup to begin with. When/If, I run the `docker build` locally, I usually `cd` in the service first and then: `docker build -f docker/Dockerfile -t app/admin --no-cache .`

Comment: This issue might be related... no `buildkit` in Azure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179040/azure-pipelines-build-a-specific-stage-in-a-multistage-dockerfile-without-build

Comment: Reading the Docker source code, it seems like this error message occurs if the Dockerfile does not have the stage specified by your target. https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/085c6a98d54720e70b28354ccec6da9b1b9e7fcf/builder/dockerfile/builder.go#L197 Are you sure that the `${{ parameters.target }}` variable is set to a valid stage name?

Comment: Yeah I've definitely checked I didn't have a typo in my stage name in the `Dockerfile`, or in the stage name I was passing into the `Docker@2` task for Azure Pipeline, and it all checks out: the stage does exist in the `Dockerfile` and it is spelled out correctly throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have it sorted out now and the pipeline stages are running successfully. It was a combination of adding `DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1` like:

```
  - task: Docker@2
    # Run if there have been changes
    displayName: ${{ parameters.taskDisplayName }}
    inputs:
      command: ${{ parameters.dockerCommand }}
      repository: $(imageRepository)-${{ parameters.service }}
      dockerfile: $(dockerFilePath)/${{ parameters.service }}/docker/Dockerfile
      buildContext: $(dockerFilePath)/${{ parameters.service }}
      containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
      arguments: --target ${{ parameters.target }}
      tags: |
        ${{ parameters.tag }}-$(Build.BuildNumber)
    env:
      DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
```

And then removing `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1` from each `Dockerfile`. Local environment still works after making the modification to the `Dockerfile` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, but fixed it in a simple way. Just use `AS` insted of `as`

Like so:

```
#FROM image as test
FROM image AS test
```

Just a small nuance

Comment: That is absurd. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error a few minutes ago.
My client service was like this before:

> ```
> services:
>   client:     
>     container_name: client
>     image: client
>     build: ./client
>     ports:
>      - '3000:3000'
>    volumes:
>      - ./client:/app
>      - ./app/node_modules
> ```

I moved the **build: ./client** at the beginning of the service and it worked for me.

After, it was like this:

> ```
> services:
>   client:     
>     build: ./client
>     container_name: client
>     image: client
>     ports:
>      - '3000:3000'
>    volumes:
>      - ./client:/app
>      - ./app/node_modules
> ```